# Creating a Huggingface Dataset with categorical class labels from a file

Tags: python, huggingface-datasets

Most (if not all) of the huggingface `datasets` examples I've found that use `ClassLabel` hard-code the list of labels, i.e. from [ag_news](https://huggingface.co/datasets/ag_news/blob/main/ag_news.py)

```py
    def _info(self):
        return datasets.DatasetInfo(
            description=_DESCRIPTION,
            features=datasets.Features(
                {
                    "text": datasets.Value("string"),
                    "label": datasets.features.ClassLabel(names=["World", "Sports", "Business", "Sci/Tech"]),
                }
            ),
            homepage="http://groups.di.unipi.it/~gulli/AG_corpus_of_news_articles.html",
            citation=_CITATION,
            task_templates=[TextClassification(text_column="text", label_column="label")],
        )
```

I'm trying to construct a dataset which has a large number of labels, and the labels have additional metadata, i.e. say I have a labels.json file containing

```
{"name":"label_1", "category":"c1", "reference":123}
{"name":"label_2", "category":"c1", "reference":456}
{"name":"label_3", "category":"c2", "reference":789}
```

(Later I want to expose the additional metadata for use at inference time but it's not relevant to this question)

I want to read this file in order to construct the `DatasetInfo`, specifically construct the `names` array when the dataset is loaded. The issue is how do I obtain the filename - the `_info` method doesn't pass the `download_manager` which afaik is required in order to locate the local copy of the file in the cache.